# Помогите пж, у меня возникла проблема я написанием бота для дискорда на python

Tags: python, sqlite3, discord.py

Объясните пж что делать т.к. я находил подобные проблемы с ответами но там про какую-то суету в коде говорилось, но ни решения и никакого внятного ответа не было. задал вопрос в дс мне сказали: "установи intents гайдов в инете полно" я еле нашёл такой гайд, я всё сделал как в видео, это только усугубило ситуацию и явно это не является решением проблемы

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


import sqlite3
from config import settings


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['PREFIX'])
client.remove_command('help')

connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('бот {0.user} запущен!'.format(client))
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT,
        rep INT,
        lvl INT
    )""")

    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id ={member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}',{member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
            else:
                pass
    connection.commit()



@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
         cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}',{member.id}, 0, 0, 1")
         connection.commit()
    else:
        pass

@client.command()
async def balance(ctx, member : discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]}**"""
        ))
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс **{member}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]}**"""
        ))




client.run(settings['TOKEN'])
```

Ошибка:

```
бот Ахмет#0014 запущен!
Ignoring exception in command balance:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\дс серв\bot.py", line 48, in balance
    description = f"""Баланс **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]}**"""
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1):

## Рефракторинг

1. Убираем все `else: pass` они не нужны.
2. Упрощаем `balance`:

```py
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.author

    amount = cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]

    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
        description=f"""Баланс **{member}** составляет **{amount}**"""
    ))
```

3. Выносим одинаковый функционал, в данном случае мы при инициализации и при заходе пользователя на сервер добавляем его в бд, если его в неё нет, также можно вынсти функциоонал получения пользователя по id и добавление пользователя, давайте же сделаем такие функции:

```py
def select_by_id(id):
    return cursor.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", (id,))


def add_member(member):
    cursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('?',?, 0, 0, 1)",
        (member, member.id))


def try_to_add_member(member):
    if select_by_id(member.id).fetchone() is None:
        add_member(member)
        return True
    return False
```

4. Избавляемся от возможной атаки с использованием SQL-инъекции:
   Заменяем всё форматирование для `execute` на безопасный механизм:
   `cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id ={member.id}")`
   ->
   `cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id =?", (member.id,))`
5. Форматируем код

Получилось это

```py
import sqlite3

import discord
from config import settings
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=settings['PREFIX'])
client.remove_command('help')

connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()


def select_by_id(id):
    return cursor.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", (id,))


def add_member(member):
    cursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('?',?, 0, 0, 1)",
        (member, member.id))


def try_to_add_member(member):
    if select_by_id(member.id).fetchone() is None:
        add_member(member)
        return True
    return False


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('бот {0.user} запущен!'.format(client))
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash BIGINT,
        rep INT,
        lvl INT
    )""")

    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            try_to_add_member(member)
    connection.commit()


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if try_to_add_member(member):
        connection.commit()


@client.command()
async def balance(ctx, member=None):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.author

    amount = select_by_id(member.id).fetchone()["cash"]

    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
        description=f"""Баланс **{member}** составляет **{amount}**"""
    ))


client.run(settings['TOKEN'])
```

## Ошибка

происходит в функцие `balance` на строке, где мы пытаемся получить `amount`, т.к. `fetchone()` возвращает `None`, и после этого пытается получить доступ к пермоу элеменнту `None` (`None[0]`), а т.к. `None` это не последовательность, то и первого элемента не существует.

Вернёмся к `fetchone()`, почему эта функция возвращает `None`?
А потому, что ваш запрос не нашёл ни одной строки с данными параметрами, в данном случае - с данным `id`.

Что нам надо сделать - обработать такой случай: (ещё по-хорошему бы разобраться, почему возникала такая ошибка, в бд ли проблема или, может, в запросах, а может ещё в чём)

```py
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx, member=None):
    if member is None:
        member = ctx.author

    row = select_by_id(member.id).fetchone()
    if row is None:
        print("Неизвестный пользователь, добавляем")
        add_member(member)
        row = select_by_id(member.id).fetchone()  # не оптимально, зато понятно

    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
        description=f"""Баланс **{member}** составляет **{row["cash"]}**"""
    ))
```

## Dicord.py

Вам стоит знать, что разработка этого пакета прекращена из-за радикальных изменений, которые вносит Discord, он ожидает, чтобы все боты перешли на новые Слэш-команды к апрелю 2022, и вам стоит этим обеспокоиться, т.к. Dicord.py, почти наверняка не будет работать к этому времени.

[Вот](https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/4a2f62751b9600a31a0d3c78100287f1) оригинальный "пост" от того, кто начал, поддерживал и теперь закрыл Dicord.py

Comment: @Сергей если вам помог или понравится этот ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Здравствуйте, а что за "слэш-команды"? можете по подробнец рассказать? просто я не нашёл никакой информации по этому поводу. и в коде котрый вы скинули та же самая ошибка в строчке 60 (amount = select_by_id(member.id).fetchone()["cash"])

Comment: @Сергей я не могу за вас отдебажить программу, вы просмотрите, добавляются ли новые пользователи в бд или нет? Также вы не предоставили никакой информации о том, как вы взаимодействуете с ботом и в какой среде работает бот (хотя бы сколько участников на сервере).

Comment: про [слеш-команды](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500000368501-Slash-Commands-FAQ)

Comment: Тем более, если вы кодили всё по гайду, то подозрение падает на взаимодействие с / саму бд

Comment: @Сергей я буду признателен, если вы хотя бы проголосуете за ответ, я постарался избавить ваш код от возможных проблем с безопасностью и в целом его улучшить, будет очень приятно, если вы это оцените.

Comment: Бота я делал по гайду в sublime text. В db все добавляется. При вводе команды balance выводит как раз ошибку. По запуске программы все отлично. Именно при вводе команды.